Where can I find the code and query implementation for GET /api/v1/chart/ endpoint in Apache Superset?
I am working with Apache Superset, and I need to understand how the /api/v1/chart/ endpoint works, specifically where the code for this endpoint is located in the Superset repository. I am looking for the Python code that handles the requests to this endpoint, as well as where the SQL or database queries generated by this endpoint are written or managed.
I have explored the Superset codebase but couldn't pinpoint the exact files or modules that define the behavior of this endpoint and how it constructs the queries.
Could anyone guide me on where to find the relevant code for this /api/v1/chart/ endpoint, including both the Python logic and the query-building part?
I explored the superset/views/ directory and examined the base_api.py file. Although I found some relevant functions like get_list_headless, I couldn't identify the exact endpoint or the specific code block where the query is constructed and executed.
I am expecting to find:
The specific file and function where the /api/v1/chart/ endpoint is defined.
The location in the code where the SQL or database queries for this endpoint are generated and executed.

